# simd_mul vs * operator

Tags: swift, xcode, simd

In many official Apple samples and Xcode templates, two `float4x4` matrices are multiplied using `simd_mul`, like:

```
simd_mul(viewMatrix, modelMatrix)
```

Now, simd.h provides a `*` operator for it's types, so the above line could have been written as

```
viewMatrix * modelMatrix
```

Is there any difference, either in usage or performance between the above two methods? I can only look into `simd.h` so I have no idea how is the method actually implemented, but I guess it's just a call to `simd_mul`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. Swift is open source, and in
[simd.swift.gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/simd/simd.swift.gyb) you'll find

```
%   for k in [2,3,4]:
  /// Matrix multiplication (the "usual" matrix product, not the elementwise
  /// product).
%    restype = ctype[type] + str(k) + 'x' + str(rows)
%    rhstype = ctype[type] + str(k) + 'x' + str(cols)
  @_transparent
  public static func *(lhs: ${mattype}, rhs: ${rhstype}) -> ${restype} {
    return simd_mul(lhs, rhs)
  }

%   end # for k in [2,3,4]
```

.gyb files (“Generate Your Boilerplate“) are pre-processed by a special
Swift preprocessor (compare https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20151207/000226.html). The above code is nested inside
loops

```
%for type in floating_types:
% for rows in [2,3,4]:
%  for cols in [2,3,4]:
%   mattype = 'simd_' + ctype[type] + str(cols) + 'x' + str(rows)

// ....

%  end # for cols in [2,3,4]
% end # for rows in [2,3,4]
%end # for type in floating_types
```

so that it ultimately expands to `*` operator definitions for all
possible matrix operand combinations.